# using 'eval' in a function produces different results than when using it in a script

Tags: bash

Say in my current directory I have files: a.1, a.2, b.1, b.2.
I have this script in file 'x':

```
echo `eval echo "$1"`
echo 'eval echo "$2"`
```

If I do:

```
> set -f; x a* b*
```

I get:

```
> a.1 a.2
> b.1 b.2
```

... Which is very nice, I can access and expand any of the command line arguments (as typed) and expand them at my pleasure.

Alas! If I put the contents of my script 'x' inside a function it no longer works, the wildcards refuse to expand. Of course I can remove the 'set -f' but then the list of arguments expands 'out of control' which is to say that I don't know where the 'b*' arguments start since I don't know how many arguments 'a*' will exand to.

Can I make the above work inside a function? And, for that matter, why does it behave differently than the same code in a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is that when you put it in a separate script `x`, and call that script using

```
x ...
```

then you're launching a separate instance of Bash to run the script (that is, it's equivalent to

```
bash x ...
```

), and that separate instance doesn't inherit the `set -f` setting, whereas when you put it in a shell function, it runs within the same instance.

One solution is to drop the whole `set -f` approach, and just quote your arguments when you call the function:

```
function x () { for arg in "$@" ; do echo $arg ; done ; }
x 'a.*' 'b.*' # prints a.1 a.2 on one line, b.1 b.2 on the next.
```

Another solution is to define the function to run in a subshell (but still within the same instance of Bash), and then cancel the `set -f` within that function by using `set +f`:

```
set -f
function x () ( set +f ; for arg in "$@" ; do echo $arg ; done )
x a.* b.* # prints a.1 a.2 on one line, b.1 b.2 on the next.
```

(The reason for using the subshell, i.e. for using `(...)` instead of `{...}` is that otherwise, the `set +f` would "leak out" of the function call. But maybe that's O.K.?)

Yet another solution is to have the function invoke a new instance of Bash:

```
set -f
function x () { for arg in "$@" ; do bash -c "echo $arg" ; done ; }
x a.* b.* # prints a.1 a.2 on one line, b.1 b.2 on the next.
```

Comment: Yes, I see, the 'subshell' thing is the difference. Lots of ideas to think about there, many thanks. I found another thing that seems to help. Brain numbing tho it is, if I just add 'set +f' to the top of the function, all is well. It seems that the first 'set -f' stops expansion, as you'd expect, but then 'set -f' inside the function permits 'eval' to do it's job, and I get exactly what I want ... but all the above is very educational.  Many thanks.

Comment: FWIW, all this agony is in the service of some wrappers I'm making for common commands (find, ls, grep, etc.). My goal is to create a standardized syntax so I don't have to run to the man page every five minutes, and that means that I need to be able to expand the command line arguments under my own control, so that I know what I'm passing to the 'real' command.

Comment: @rayandrews: To clarify, a subshell *does* inherit the `set -f` setting from its parent; it's only when you invoke a whole new instance of Bash that the `set -f` setting is not passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial `set -f` affects only the current shell instance. When you launch your script, a new shell is started, and that shell has globbing enabled. If you replace the script with the function, the function runs in the context of the shell where `set -f` has effect, and so no globbing takes place.

You actually don't need to disable globbing to get the behaviour you want. You need only quote the arguments to your function:

```
myfunc()
{
    echo $1
    echo $2
}

myfunc "a.*" "b.*"
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can quote, but I'm trying to avoid it since these wrappers I'm making are for the commands I use constantly. Typing economy is the whole point.